# ActiveRecordBase does not have OnCreate

Tags: castle-activerecord

`ActiveRecordBase` has both `OnSave` and `OnUpdate` but does not have `OnCreate`, why and how can it be implemented? I'm using `IsUnsaved` in `OnUpdate` to determine if this is a Create or an Edit operation. Is there any better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `OnCreate` because ActiveRecord "events" are based on NHibernate's IInterceptor, and IInterceptor doesn't have any `OnCreate`.

However, `OnSave` is called for new persistent objects only, and `OnUpdate` only for updates, so there is no need to check `IsUnsaved` anywhere. [Here's the test](http://github.com/castleproject/Castle.ActiveRecord/blob/b0f79729c3717262b1e66d356b1f83eba1b89019/src/Castle.ActiveRecord.Tests/ActiveRecordTestCase.cs#L589) that covers this.